# Error when trying to go to the folder by command line after instaling sumo

Tags: command-line, software-installation

```
$ sudo apt-get install sumo sumo-tools sumo-doc
[sudo] password for my: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sumo is already the newest version (0.27.1+dfsg1-1).
sumo-doc is already the newest version (0.27.1+dfsg1-1).
sumo-tools is already the newest version (0.27.1+dfsg1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 190 not upgraded.
my@my-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cd'/home/my/Downloads/sumo-0.30.0' 
bash: cd/home/my/Downloads/sumo-0.30.0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please run `ls -a` and paste the output

Answer (score 2):

APT does not download to your `Downloads` directory. It stores its cached files in `/var/cache/apt` but you mostly do not need to access these files directly.

There is one more problem with your `cd` command: You are missing a space between the command and the path.

However, you do not have to access `Downloads` folder to run `sumo`. Once you have installed the requested package `sumo` using APT (you *have* installed it already according to `sumo is already the newest version`), you can simply run the commands `sumo`, `sumo-gui` etc. in your terminal.

(My guesses of the command names are based on https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/sumo/filelist, have not installed `sumo` myself.)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a space in the command:

```
cd'/home/my/Downloads/sumo-0.30.0'
```

Change to:

```
cd '/home/my/Downloads/sumo-0.30.0'
```